# To display python script containing image file using crontab

Tags: python-2.7, cron, embedded-linux, debian-based

I am Newbie to Python programming. I am trying to run a python script which has an image file(.jpg). I want to run the script using cron but it doesn't seem to work. This is what I entered in `crontab -e`:

```
@reboot python /home/debian/Desktop/file.py &
```

This works fine with other Python files but doesn't work with image files.
Can anyone please help me out with this and justify why this happens only when I deal with images.